# Pyinstaller on project with modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to do a one file exe on my python 3.7 project with Pyinstaller. I have structured the project with package and modules and when I start the project from the terminal (Mac) it's working fine.

From terminal and in a folder one step above the project -

```
python3 -m my_module.mymain
```

I have tried -

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed my_module.mymain
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed my_module.mymain.py
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed mymain
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed mymain.py
```

the last two in the same folder as the mymain.py.

Nothing of the above works, thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to generate a separate executable from your packages?
What is your error? Please be more specific and give your code for better help.

Answer (score 0):

First a python shell then import the wanted module and do :

```py
import my_module
print(my_module.__file__)
```

Then you will have the file of your module, then simply do pyinstaller on this file.

If that doesn't work create a micro python file just firing your module and execute pyinstaller on this file.

PS:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed my_module.mymain.py
```

Doesn't work because here you never said to pyinstaller to read from module, here pyinstaller try to read a file named my_module.mymain.py in the current directory.